# Turpentine diasable cache for footer reference

Tags: cache, varnish, turpentine

In checkout i use anather footer.

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/html/footer/footer-bottom-checkout.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

in turpentine_esi.xml i have code

```
<opc_index_index>
    <turpentine_cache_flag value="0"/>
</opc_index_index>
```

But footer is in cache and does not change, the default template is loaded page/html/footer.phtml

How I can remowe footer from ceche?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this, which will set it up so the footer block is hole-punched with no caching.

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <ttl>0</ttl>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```